# How to make various images in grid view clickable to different activity?

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-activity, clickable

I make a grid view v=with various images targetting to various activities but i don't know about how to make these images clickable to display next activity. I know it can be done through onItemClickListener but i don't know how to do it. Plz help me out ! Any kinda help would be appreciated...!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use an ImageButton, but ok.

Say for each image you've got something like:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView();
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.foo);
```

Your Grid activity should implement View.OnClickListener, with a method something like:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNextActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and then, your ImageView creation should be something like:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView();
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.foo);
iv.setOnClickListener(this); // Reference to the OnClickListener implementation
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please share your relevant code and, if there's an exception, the LogCat from DDMS